# Python: Short way of creating a sequential list with a prefix

Tags: python

how can I generate a string (or Pandas series) like below:

```
a1,a2,a3,a4,...,a19
```

the following works, but I would like to know a shorter way

```
my_str = ""
for i in range(1, 20):
   comma = ',' if i!= 19 else ''
   my_str += "d" + str(i) + comma
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can just use a list comprehension to generate the individual elements (using string concatenation or [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format)), and then [join](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) the resulting list on the separator string (the comma):

```
>>> ['a{}'.format(i) for i in range(1, 20)]
['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4', 'a5', 'a6', 'a7', 'a8', 'a9', 'a10', 'a11', 'a12', 'a13', 'a14', 'a15', 'a16', 'a17', 'a18', 'a19']
>>> ','.join(['a{}'.format(i) for i in range(1, 20)])
'a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,a7,a8,a9,a10,a11,a12,a13,a14,a15,a16,a17,a18,a19'
```

Answer (score 2):

What about:

```
s = ','.join(["a%d" % i for i in range(1,20)])
print(s)
```

Output:

```
a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,a7,a8,a9,a10,a11,a12,a13,a14,a15,a16,a17,a18,a19
```

<s>(This uses a generator expression, which is more efficient than joining over a list comprehension -- only slightly, with such a short list, however)</s>  This now uses a list comprehension!  See comments for an interesting read about why list comprehensions are more appropriate than generator expressions for `join`.

Comment: You have redundant parenthesis: `','.join("a%d" % i for i in range(1,20))`

Comment: Unlike common belief, joining on a generator expression is *not* more efficient than joining on a list directly. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9061024/216074) for details.

Comment: @DanD. they're not redundant, they're explicit -- if you were to need additional arguments to the outer function (`join`, in this case), you would need them.

Comment: @poke, I could never argue with Raymond Hettinger -- will update accordingly.

Comment: @jedwards There are no other possible arguments to `str.join`.

Comment: @poke, I agree.  But in the spirit of "explicit is better than implicit", I tend to leave them, to avoid future confusion.  If the same generator were applied to say, `max(..., key=...)`, it would be an odd use indeed, but you would need the parens.

Answer (score 1):

Adding onto what poke said (which I found to be the most helpful), but bringing it into 2022:

```
[f'a{i}' for i in range(1, 21)]
```