# Create a list with string + range

Tags: python, list, range

I need your help:

I want to create a list looking like this `['Unnamed: 16', 'Unnamed: 17', 'Unnamed:18']` for a range (16,60). How can I proceed?

I don't know if my question is clear but it's like doing `list(range(16, 60)` but with a string before each numbers.

Thank you very much for your help!!

Comment: `[f"whatever {i}" for i in range(...)]`

Comment: First of all you didn’t format your code properly you have a missing bracket.

Also don’t ask how to write code, see “How to ask Questions”.
Instead show what you have tried.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29339525/python-short-way-of-creating-a-sequential-list-with-a-prefix

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#formatted-string-literals) to do so :

```
my_list = [f"Unnamed: {i}" for i in range(16, 60)]

# Output
['Unnamed: 16', 'Unnamed: 17', 'Unnamed: 18', 'Unnamed: 19', ...]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it following way

```
prefix = "Unnamed: "
lst = [prefix + str(i) for i in range(16,25)]
print(lst)
```

output

```
['Unnamed: 16', 'Unnamed: 17', 'Unnamed: 18', 'Unnamed: 19', 'Unnamed: 20', 'Unnamed: 21', 'Unnamed: 22', 'Unnamed: 23', 'Unnamed: 24']
```

Note: I used othre range for brevity sake. You might elect to use one of string formatting method instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using map as,

```
list(map(lambda x: f'Unnamed: {x}', range(16, 60)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use f strings

```py
name = 'Unamed:'
list = [f"{prefix} {i}" for i in range(16, 60)]
print(list)
```

Answer (score -1):

```py
my_list = []

for i in range(16, 60):

    my_list.append("Unnamed: " + str(i))

print(my_list)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).